# How to disable promiscuous mode in hyper-v?

Tags: windows-11, hyper-v, kali-linux, wireshark

I enable promiscuous mode on hyper-V system(windows 11) following by
[hypervPromiscuousModeSetUp](https://docs.tenable.com/nnm/Content/HyperVPromiscuousMode.htm)

I test wireshark on hyper-v running Kali linux OS, It works well.

But, I want to disable promiscuous Mode on hyper-v system now. How can I disable promiscuous Mode on hyper-v system?

Thank you.

Comment: Change the monitor mode setting to non-monitoring in the instructions you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complications and limitations of the PowerShell cmdlets outlined above led to writing a simplified set of PowerShell commands, where enabling port monitoring on external or internal switches gets as simple as:

```
Import-Module .\VMSwitchPortMonitorMode.psm1

Set-VMSwitchPortMonitorMode -SwitchName MySwitch -MonitorMode Source
```

The module is available  [here](https://github.com/cloudbase/unattended-setup-scripts/blob/master/VMSwitchPortMonitorMode.psm1)

How to check the status of port monitoring on a given switch:

```
PS C:\Dev> Get-VMSwitchPortMonitorMode MySwitch
PortType   MonitorMode
--------   -----------
External   Source>
```

Disabling monitoring is also very easy:

Set-VMSwitchPortMonitorMode -SwitchName MySwitch -MonitorMode None

Source: https://cloudbase.it/hyper-v-promiscuous-mode/

Answer (score 0):

According to the article
[Configure traffic mirroring with a Hyper-V vSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-iot/organizations/traffic-mirroring/configure-mirror-hyper-v)
`MonitorMode=0` means "None".

It might be simpler to just create the switch anew in normal mode.

Comment: Thanks for giving advice. As the article, only set `MonitorMode=2` as work as promiscuous Mode? [hypervPromiscuousModeSetUp](https://docs.tenable.com/nnm/Content/HyperVPromiscuousMode.htm) Here says that set `MonitorMode=2` and also set physical mac address on host computer to do port mirroring. I already set port mirroring with my physical mac address, so I wonder that just change `MonitorMode=0` can disable premiscuous mode.

Comment: and According to the article [configure traffic mirroring with a hyper-v vswitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-iot/organizations/traffic-mirroring/configure-mirror-hyper-v)hyperV does not needed port mirroring to work as premiscuous mode, only needed `monitorMode=2` right?

I'm so confused why [hypervPromiscuousModeSetup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-iot/organizations/traffic-mirroring/configure-mirror-hyper-v) teaches to set port mirroring.